# Can't use HOUR() because Excel doesn't recognize a time

Tags: excel, time, format

Excel doesn't recognize a time column so I'm unable to parse the hour from it using =HOUR().

I've tried formatting the column of datetimes (formatted dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM) as date and time using Excel formatting, and also tried pulling the datevalue using =DATEVALUE(), but always end up with a #VALUE! error.

```
time              hour ("=HOUR(A2)")
29/05/2018 16:20  #VALUE!
29/05/2018 16:25  #VALUE!
29/05/2018 16:30  #VALUE!
```

I would expect if the cells are formatted properly then the hour (16) should be returned, but instead it is just the #VALUE! error, so there must be some formatting issue, but I can't figure out what it is or how to fix it.

Comment: Most likely your dates are strings. If you change the formatting do the dates changed their appearance in the cell

Comment: @RonRosenfeld No, the appearance doesn't change when I edit the formatting

Comment: Are you trying to specifically fix this so you can use `HOUR()`?  There are other ways to get the hour if your cells are all formatted that way (`dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm`)

Comment: @BruceWayne HOUR() isn't essential, but I need to sort the data by a specific range of times and I'm using HOUR() as a helper column. I could take a substring and convert it to an integer but because the time is on a 24-hour clock the length of the substring changes (e.g. 8:00 is one character shorter than 12:00).

Comment: Then your values are text, no matter the formatting.

Comment: Please see https://superuser.com/q/299437/52365.

Comment: I am guessing someone/thing else has produced this file. It looks like it was produced using a system that had "dd/mm/yyyy" as its Regional Setting. On my system (same setting) the HOUR() function works fine. If you are in the US, then likely your Regional setting (found in Windows settings) will be set to "mm/dd/yyyy" so the other date format confuses Excel (or it would convert automatically).  To just get the hour, use =HOUR(VALUE(TRIM(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND(" ",A2))))).

Answer (score 1):

Your values are *Text* rather than true date/times.  Use:

```
=--MID(A1,12,2)
```

instead:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your values are text, and it is likely that your windows regional settings are MDY.

Best solution:
   Go back to the source and convert properly when importing into Excel.  Especially if you are importing a text or csv file.

Possible solution if ALL of your values are text:
   Use Data Text-toColumns wizard.
   Split between the date and the time
   For the date column, select DMY for the format

If some of the values are text, and others real dates, then you will have to convert the text values to dates first, and not alter the real date values.  Best way:  see "best" solution, but we'd need more information.

Answer (score 0):

In the event you have `8:10` instead of `08:10`, you can use this to capture just the hour:

```
=--TRIM(MID(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1),SEARCH(":",A1)-SEARCH(" ",A1)))
```

[image]